# Spring data elasticsearch query on multiple indices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have multiple indices for every day in elasticsearch and I am using `ElasticsearchRepository` to query my documents. Documents definition:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "fraud-hub-digital-transactions-#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now().toString()}", createIndex = false)
@TypeAlias("fraud-hub-digital-transactions")
public class FraudDigitalTransactions {
    
    @Id
    @Field(name = "transaction_key",type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long transactionId;
    
    @Field(name = "client_no",type = FieldType.Integer)
    private Integer clientNo;
}
```

My index will create dynamically for every day with this definition

```
@Document(indexName = "fraud-hub-digital-transactions-#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now().toString()}"
```

My Repository definition:

```
@Repository
public interface FraudDigitalTransactionsRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<FraudDigitalTransactions,String> {
    List<FraudDigitalTransactions> findByClientNo(Integer clientNo);
}
```

When I query by client no just returning current day values.

```
@Test
public void testFindByClientNo() {
    List<FraudDigitalTransactions> fraudDigitalTransactions = fraudDigitalTransactionsRepository.findByClientNo(88019237);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(fraudDigitalTransactions.size(),0);
}
```

Test failed. Current day values returned not searched all indices.
Probably Spring data searching a document in current day indexes. Is there any way with spring data to search all indexes? I can do it with elasticsearch high-level client but I want to do with spring data features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to search with a wildcard or alias and when writing use the index name produced by the bean.

I recently wrote a [blog post](https://www.sothawo.com/2020/11/implement-a-rolling-index-strategy-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-4-1/) how to do this with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1 using index templates.

Comment: Great. Spring team really proactive. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not part of the Spring Team; Spring Data Elasticsearch is a community project ;-)

Comment: Indexes puttemplate command for alias is not working while index document does not exist. I tried create an index manually and batch uploaded data from logstash, spring application could not give alias to this index.