# how to sort msearch results among several indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to make a query to several indexes to match one criterion.
I use "multisearch" to search among several indexes. Java code below:

> List<SearchHits<?>> searchHits = searchOperations.multiSearch(queryList, classList, indexCoordinatesList);

The result is given in accordance with the "score" for each index separately, that is, first sorting by "score" in one index, then in another, and so on.
But it is clear that it is necessary to sort the whole result as a whole, and not separately for each index.
I didn't find the answer either in the Spring Data Elasticsearch documentation or in the Elasticsearch Guide.
That is, in fact, I have two questions:

1. Is there a method in the Query or BaseQuery classes to apply one
   query to multiple indexes, or each query of these classes to only
   one index?
2. Do I understand correctly that the application of "searchOperations.multiSearch(...)" allows sorting only at the level of sorters from java libraries, and not at the level of elasticsearch?
   In general, I try to sort at the elasticsearch level.

If anyone can tell me which method of Query classes or in BaseQuery should be used, I would be especially grateful.

Comment: Instead of using multiSearch you need to use normal search with multiple indices which does exactly what you are trying to achieve. So the real question is how do I use search with multiple indices, and that question was already answered in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036671/783043

Comment: The post you specified relates to the formation of indexes with an alias. If this is such a hint about the use of aliases, then thank you. But the question is complicated by the need to apply four different queries, such as "Query query = Native Query.builder()...", in different indexes, and the whole result must be sorted by "score", but not separately in each query.

Comment: I added an example on how to run different subqueries on different indices within the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing mSearch, you need to perform normal search while combining queries together. This might create somewhat incompatible scores so you might need to apply boost while merging them together. This is a simple example that searches two indices with different queries while boosting scores from the first index. It uses a term query on the special ['_index'](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) field to filter out specific indices.

```
DELETE test_foo
DELETE test_bar

POST _bulk?refresh
{"index": {"_index": "test_foo"}}
{"foo": "This is a test"}
{"index": {"_index": "test_bar"}}
{"bar": "How does this work?"}

GET test_foo,test_bar/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "foo": "test"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "test_foo"
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 2.0
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "bar": "work"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "test_bar"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @imotov.
To solve my question, I used a "alias":

```
POST:localhost:9200/_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "native_film_index", "alias" : "alias_cinema"}},
        { "add" : { "index" : "serial_index", "alias" : "alias_cinema"}},
        { "add" : { "index" : "directors_index", "alias" : "alias_cinema"}},
        { "add" : { "index" : "actors_index", "alias" : "alias_cinema"}}
    ]
}
```

I made a request to the name "alias_cinema", and in the request I specified the names of the fields of the documents of the corresponding indexes.
It works in elasticsearch, but I don't know how to make such a request in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Does "Spring Data Elasticsearch" allow accessing indexes via "alias"? If so, how?

Comment: To search with one query for several indexes in "Spring Data ES", I created an object "IndexCoordinates", in which I added the names of the indexes I needed. The result is expected. But I ran into a problem: some documents of the query result are defined as the type of the corresponding user class, but some are defined as "LinkedHashMap". At the same time, there is no such situation for any other query for each index separately.
Full description at the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77402532/20460673